# Re-define escape function in an XSS attack using URL hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

This is related to [XSS attack](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9521) using jQuery selector. I'm reading the url hash in my  code. If I have a malformed URL like this

`http://www.example.com/#<img src='/' onerror='alert(1)'>`

A safe way to get around would be have an `escape` function in my code (e.g. [_.escape](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1245)) before creating a selector (I know I can avoid this with `$('body').find(...)` but my question isn't about avoiding it)

```
var wHash = escape(window.location.hash.replace('#',''));
$(wHash);
```

**Question:** Is it possible to re-define `escape` inside the payload, to render it useless. Something like this:

```
<img src='/' onerror='(function(){window.escape = function(x) { return x; } })()'>
```

I can't precisely craft this to make it work, but I'm wondering what's stopping the attacker from re-defining the `escaping` part of the code from the url hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wHash = escape(…)` is executed *before* `$(wHash)`, which would create the image element from `<img …>`. But as `escape` is mangling the value *before* it is evaluated by `$`, the `escape` function redefinition would only happen *after* it has already been called.

Comment: But subsequent calls to escape won't work since it's been re-defined. Modifying the url hash won't reload the good code either.

Comment: Well, `escape` mitigates the vulnerability since it encodes characters like `<` and `>` using percent-encoding. So you won’t even come to the point where the mentioned code would redefine `escape`.

Comment: makes sense. this from your answer : `escape function redefinition would only happen after` made me think that redefinition was getting executed.